Identifying Period Molding In-Situ
I’d like to have some molding milled.
However, to approach the local shop/mill, it would be useful if I could name the molding/spindle cutters used.
Therefore, I've attached a photo of the molding.

It is 75mm wide, 45mm deep.
The molding is defined by a central arc.
external to the arc, it has one design.
and internal to the arc, a separate design.

I wondered if someone could help me define the cutters used internal/external to the arc, for replication purposes?
Any help would be appreciated on naming the external/internal cutters used, as id like to replicate on internal doors (including Mason mitres)
As shown in the photos, the moldings are long gone. Boarded over in the 70s and discarded. But it would be nice to replicate similar.
For context, this is an Edwardian home in Scotland built around 1900.
Many thanks



75mm wide, 45mm deep... What does that mean? Internal/external to the arc - huh? I know these make perfect sense to you, but they're not describing much to me. Really, though, no amount of words will make a bit of difference to someone trying to replicate this. You really need to bring a sample or a mold of a sample to the shop that's going to reproduce it for you. Or, have them come to you to take a mold. It's the only way they're going to get close.

Identifying period moulding...... a lot of period mouldings are not something that has a name.
At least not any more — they may have had a name in-period, in 'style' books from which they were taken, but major or minor variations abound when it comes down to the details1.

to approach the local shop/mill, it would be useful if I could name the molding/spindle cutters used.

Here where you might have the ideal course of action a little backward. Instead of trying to do it on your end, let them, with their specific expertise, guide you.
Bringing a moulding sample, or an accurate profile (see below), to the mill. Regardless of whether there's a name for it they'll certainly know if they have that style and whether an exact equivalent needs a custom moulder head.
You really need to strip a moulding covered with this much paint to get a proper idea of what it looks like, and this will greatly clarify the profile. After that it's straightforward to remove a piece to bring in (or mail in) to the intended supplier of the new moulding2.

1 Because of the variable ways they may have been made at the time; long after production millwork was possible due to powered machinery, mouldings could still be produced in the workshop or on the job site by hand, using whatever combination of moulding planes or scraper tools the local artisan(s) had on hand. This would be especially the case where a run of millwork brought in for the job ran out, and only a small amount of extra material was then required. This can e.g. account for some houses, even individual rooms, having two versions of 'the same' moulding pattern.
2 If you don't fancy prising off a piece you can take a mould using a variety of materials (Oyumaru, Sugru, plaster of Paris if you're careful) and use that instead.

Hi @Graphus. Appreciate your feedback - but in terms of 'backwards' - no. 'Cautious' - yes. Of course I know I can take a sample to a mill, but to extract a sample would do significant damage to existing, so I tried to minimise damage in case it couldn't be replicated and ask around in the first instance. But your footnote on the Blue Stuff is useful - I will try that; thank you

This: https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/tools/hand-tools/marking-and-measuring/32523-stainless-steel-tracing-profile-gauge?item=44K1402 or something like it with fine teeth (not the plastic ones) will save the step of making a casting. I'm sure your molding shop will be able to reproduce from a scale drawing.

Or a similar profile gauge from an off-shore manufacturer that can probably be had for 1/2 the price (or less) will be more than suitable for a (likely) one-time use.

Profile gauges are kinda notorious for not being good enough to get a true like-for-like match (e.g. because of 'low resolution', and lack of a locking feature) hence me not mentioning them. Castings give you an exact picture of the profile, and cheaper, way way cheaper.

@AloysiusDefenestrate, "will save the step of making a casting" Horses for courses, but...... castings are/can be cheaper, don't have to be one-use-only as they were in the past, take only a small amount of extra time and for that minor hit you get a far more accurate reproduction. Did you see how much a pack of Oyumaru/Polymorph/Polydoh etc. costs? In addition to all that, not a one trick pony, so full of win.

Fair comments all. Agree that the profile gauge linked is not cheap, but it does offer high resolution and doesn’t wiggle around after setting a profile. It is also not a sole use tool, thus possibly worth investing in. Ymmv.

One can tape the pins of a profile gauge in place to "lock" it, and, once a line is drawn on paper/card stock/wood, all the low resolutionyness of it is gone. I would think that it would do well for a "good enough" solution that doesn't involve removing the trim, and, if the paint isn't stripped from the sample piece, "good enough" is the best one can expect. ;)

@FreeMan, fair point I guess on the good enough... except I can't help but think a resolution arguably in excess of 100 times higher, introducing less error, is just inherently a better way to go (plus, to beat the dead horse, not a uni-tasker). And elephant in the room: there's no way one is getting anything even remotely like a faithful reproduction without stripping when trim/moulding/skirting is old and has been painted over numerous times; I'm sure you've seen some of the same This Old House episodes I have where stripping has revealed m a n y layers of paint. Like "HS! how many?" :-)
